# How can I open application's windows on dock separately like Windows 7?

Tags: dock

I'm new to OS X.

If I open multiple Excel workbooks, how can I see each workbook opened separately on the dock?

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native methods closest to what you want are:

- Right clicking Dock icon, as mentioned by @JBallin

  - That will show a context list, which will include the titles of the open windows for that application
- There's also the mission control feature that will show all open windows for the currently active application. You can find the shortcut in: `System Preferences > Mission Control` and there `Application windows`. I'm fairly sure you can set touch gestures for this as well. You should find that in `System Preferences > Trackpad`

---

---

If the native methods don't work for you, there's always the option to use third party applications.

There's a 3rd party Dock replacement called [**uBar** ($20)](https://brawersoftware.com/products/ubar). There's a trial available.

[image]

- You can stop some applications from showing up in the dock, which is not very doable off the box with the native Dock.
- Has window previews and option to group application windows (kinda like in Windows).
- Ordering options: `Manual`, `Alphabetical`, `Launch` <sub><sup>I love the manual order. I can make sure that when I open adobe applications, for example, they always open next to each other at the top of my uBar.</sup></sub>
- You'll likely want to hide native Dock. You can find terminal commands for that in [here](https://brawersoftware.com/products/ubar/documentation#uBarDocumentationApplicationSupportIcons). It just hides it so that you are never likely to accidentally show it. You need the second to last terminal command. You can still easily toggle the native Dock open via the shortcut `Cmd+Alt+D`. The reason why I occasionally have the need to show the native dock is to assign which space I want an application to go to, which you do by right-clicking an icon in the dock and choosing: `Options > Assing To:`(at the bottom of the list). This is not a feature in uBar, so...

> Note that uBar has quite a few customization options, but I'd say it has two distinct styles. First style is very Windows Taskbar like, as shown in that picture above. The second style is closer to the modern Dock look:  [image]

---

---

Another alternative or addition could be [**HyperSwitch** (free beta)](https://bahoom.com/hyperswitch). <sup><sub>I use both of these 3rd party applications.</sub></sup>

- It has option to show previews of windows when using `cmd+tab`

  - It works by either `cmd+tab`:ing or hovering over the icon with a mouse. You can choose which window to open by navigating with arrow keys or of course clicking with mouse.
  - [image]
- It also has it's own alternative application switcher which can show each application window, instead the application icon, which is more like the windows application switcher. It can also be made to show only application windows in the current space, which is super useful for people who use spaces a lot.

Comment: uBar also has ungroup window option. The most wanted feature i need. Awesome!!!

Comment: @praHoc Great :)

Comment: One major feature missing from uBar is the option to right click and open a new window. Otherwise, it pretty much is a complete solution.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure this isn't possible as I don't see a way in settings, here are some workarounds:

1. Minimized windows will show up in dock if "minimize windows into application icon" isn't checked in dock preferences (right click on dock to pull them up).
2. If all windows are not minimized you can swipe up with three fingers to show all windows. You can also cycle through windows by pressing <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>
3. Right click the excel icon in dock to display all open workbooks.

Comment: Thank,  Currently I use the 3 options as you suggest plus full screen 4 finger swipe, but this is not what I want. It is not because I used to the Windows but because it does not make my work easy. is there an external app?